# How can I get rid of the STDERR in Perl

Tags: perl, redirect, stderr, system-calls

I'm using some system commands in Perl.

In the below case I was getting output as follows:

```
ls: import-log.*: No such file or directory

ls: error-log.*: No such file or directory

No specified files found for deletion
```

**My code:**

```
sub monthoryear() 
{

  @importlog = `ls -al import-log.*`;

  @errorlog = `ls -al error-log.*`;

}
```

**I don't want to see the following in the output even if there are no files.**

```
ls: import-log.*: No such file or directory &

ls: error-log.*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `stderr` redirection in your subshell commands:

```
@importlog = `ls -al import-log.* 2>/dev/null`;
@errorlog = `ls -al error-log.* 2>/dev/null`;
```

Comment: @Sunny - you can use a file instead of /dev/null in that case, just replace with /path/to/file

Comment: can i get that in a variable?

Comment: To capture STDERR, see [perlfaq8: How can I capture STDERR from an external command?](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfaq8#How_can_I_capture_STDERR_from_an_external_command?)

Answer (score 15):

While the other answers are correct about the exact technical question you asked, you should also consider not writing what is effectively a shell script in Perl.

You should use Perl native methods of getting file list (e.g. `glob()` or `File::Find`) instead of calling a backticked `ls`.

Comment: This is actually the right answer. Doing it in Perl means you can capture the output into a variable without resorting to redirecting STDERR which could result in spooky action at a distance.

Answer (score 9):

Redirect STDERR to the null device:

```
use File::Spec;
open STDERR, '>', File::Spec->devnull() or die "could not open STDERR: $!\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3F). If you don't care if it's `STDOUT` or `STDERR`, you can get both redirected to `STDOUT`.

```
$output = `$cmd 2>&1`;
```

In your case, you probably just want to get rid of `STDERR`:

```
$output = `$cmd 2>/dev/null`;
```

However, I agree with [DVK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120542/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-stderr-in-perl/5120677#5120677). Using an external command to get a list of files just seems silly. You should use [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html). This way you can use Perl's normal error handling in case something fails.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @importlog;
my @errorlog;
find(sub {
    push @importlog, $File::Find::name if /^import-log\.*/;
    push @errorlog, $File::Find::name if /^error-log\.*/;
}, '.');

print "Import log:\n", join("\n", @importlog), "\n";
print "Error log:\n", join("\n", @errorlog), "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new warn hook, then do something with the message, store it, ignore it etc...

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
  my $message = shift;

  ## do nothing to ignore all together

  ## ignore specific message
  # warn $message unless $message =~ /No such file or directory/;

  ## or do something else
  # die $message ## make fatal
  # open my $fh, '>', 'file.log'; print $fh $message;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the `stderr` to `/dev/null` as:

```
@importlog = `ls -al import-log.* 2> /dev/null`;

@errorlog = `ls -al error-log.* 2> /dev/null`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Subshells will inherit the parent's STDERR, so if you want to do it on a global level, you can do this:

```
open(STDERR,'>/dev/null');
`ls non-existent-file`;
`ls non-existent-file2`;
`ls non-existent-file3`;
`ls non-existent-file4`;
`ls non-existent-file5`;
```

Comment: You should use the three argument open and File::Spec to get the null device:

Answer (score 0):

Often you also want to restore `STDERR` later. I do this like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print STDERR "This will be send to the old (readable) STDERR\n";

my $oldstderr = readlink "/proc/self/fd/2"; #Remember the location of the old STDERR
open(STDERR, ">/dev/null"); #Ignore STDERR now

print STDERR "This will be send to a STDERR that is 'gone'\n";

open(STDERR, ">$oldstderr"); #restores STDERR to the old state

print STDERR "This will be send to the old (readable) STDERR again\n";
```

**OR**

You can use the `Capture::Tiny` module which makes it easier to read and more portable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Capture::Tiny qw/capture_stderr/;

print STDERR "This will be send to the old (readable) STDERR\n";
capture_stderr sub {
  print STDERR "This will be send to a STDERR that is 'gone'\n";
};
print STDERR "This will be send to the old (readable) STDERR again\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can suppress STDERR, capture error messages that occur while turned off, restore STDERR, and report back any captured error messages.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print STDERR "STDERR is on.\n";
my ($stderr_fh, $err_msg_ref) = suppress_std_err();
print "STDERR is now off and error messages are being suppressed and saved.\n";
print STDERR "I'm an error message.\n";
restore_std_err($stderr_fh);
print STDERR "STDERR is back on\n";
print "Errors reported while STDERR was off: $$err_msg_ref\n";

#Saves STDERR in filehandle then turns it off.
#Any error messages that occur while STDERR is off are stored for safekeeping.
sub suppress_std_err {
        my $suppressed_std_error_messages;
        open (my $saved_std_err_fh, ">&", STDERR);
        close STDERR;
        open (STDERR, ">", \$suppressed_std_error_messages);
        return ($saved_std_err_fh, \$suppressed_std_error_messages);
}

#Restores STDERR from saved filehandle.
sub restore_std_err {
        my $old_std_err_fh = shift;
        close STDERR;
        open (STDERR, ">&", $old_std_err_fh);
}
```